# How to put a Tabview inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing application for Android 3.2 tablets. I have divided the UI to two panels. One is list of options using ListFragment and the second one for details using a normal Fragment class name "DetailsFragment". How would I put a TabView inside this details fragment ?

Thanks in advance